# Correctly using 'this' to print value of a button inside a form (in vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm a server-side dev (Python/Django) trying my hand on vanilla JS to learn the ropes. I'm working with a simple `<form>` that has three `<button>`s in it. For instance:

```
<form action="{% url 'an_action' %}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <button type="submit" onclick="resp()" name="btn" value="1">OK_1</button>
   <button type="submit" onclick="resp()" name="btn" value="2">OK_2</button>
   <button type="submit" onclick="resp()" name="btn" value="3">OK_3</button>
</form>
```

*Ignore the `{%` type syntax - that's Django*

My objective is to simply print the `value` inherent in each button element, once that button is pressed.

Ergo, the simple JS I wrote for it is:

```
<script>
function resp(){
    alert(this.value);
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately, that results in:

[image]

My expectation was it would print the `value` of the button I pressed. E.g. if I pressed the button with `value="2"`, the alert would print `2`.

Conceptually, what am I doing wrong and what's the way to do it right (vanilla JS only, no JQuery)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `this` as an explicit argument to the function.

```js
function resp(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
}
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'an_action' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="button" onclick="resp(this)" name="btn" value="1">OK_1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="resp(this)" name="btn" value="2">OK_2</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="resp(this)" name="btn" value="3">OK_3</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could use `addEventListener` instead of inline Javascript.

```js
function resp() {
  console.log(this.value);
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[name=btn]");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", resp);
}
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'an_action' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="button" name="btn" value="1">OK_1</button>
  <button type="button" name="btn" value="2">OK_2</button>
  <button type="button" name="btn" value="3">OK_3</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Being a server-side dev, I spend time thinking about computing efficiency as well. I'm guessing that the `for` loop would perform slower in this particular case, correct? The former method of doing this `O(1)`, whereas the latter is `O(n)`? Just confirming.

Comment: The former method is also `O(n)`, because the browser has to parse `onclick="resp(this)"` N times and create those same N bindings. Also, using `onclick` means it has to interpret the Javascript when the user clicks.

Comment: Ah, so regardless of which method, the computing time scales linearly with the number of button elements (in this case) on the page. Conceptually, I was under the impression that's not how `this` works in a situation like this. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Either way, it's just a one-time cost when the page is loaded. When the user actually clicks, they're both O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Your `resp` function doesn't automatically get a useful `this` value. You can pass `this` into the function and use it there.

```js
function resp(button){
    alert(button.value);
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
   <button type="submit" onclick="resp(this)" name="btn" value="1">OK_1</button>
   <button type="submit" onclick="resp(this)" name="btn" value="2">OK_2</button>
   <button type="submit" onclick="resp(this)" name="btn" value="3">OK_3</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<button type="submit" onclick="resp(event)" name="btn" value="1">OK_1</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="resp(event)" name="btn" value="2">OK_2</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="resp(event)" name="btn" value="3">OK_3</button>
```

JS

```
function resp(event){
    alert(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

You'd need to pass in the event parameter and use the currentTarget property to get the element which was clicked.

Comment: Use a stack snippet if you want to make this work properly.